# Signal Processing of Long Term Behavior in Stochastic Systems

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, stochastic

I am quite new to techniques of signal processing. I have a fairly generic problem and wish to find information about topics and/or techniques that may help me address this problem.

Let $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ be stochastic processes. We assume (through qualitative reasoning for instance) that $y(t)$ is "affected" by $x(t)$. We wish to model the relationship between these processes using techniques of signal processing. Moreover, $x(t)$ has output which is bounded whereas the output of $y(t)$ is unbounded, but moves continuously in time. Ultimately, we wish to estimate the expected value future values of $y(t)$ given the current and past states of $x(t)$.

I am interested in viewing this problem under the lens of signal processing because at a high level, this seems similar to understanding how to recover the impulse response of a system given empirical data (i.e. the time series data for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$). Specifically, is it standard in such a problem to try to compute a suitable impulse response function $h(t)$ such that:

$y(t) = (x\ast h)(t)$

where $\ast$ denotes the convolution. I understand the format of my question is extremely relaxed, but anything addressing this general idea even if additional structure needs to be imposed on $x$ and $y$ is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of estimating $h(t)$ given both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

One is to compute the Fourier Transforms of both and get the transfer function

$$ H(f) = \frac{Y(f)}{X(f)} $$

Then inverse Fourier Transform $H(f)$.

Another is to use cross-correlation

$$ h(t) = \overline{y(u) \cdot x(t+u)} $$

Another is to use an LMS adaptive filter with $x(t)$ as FIR input and $y(t)$ as the *"desired signal"* input.  If you want that explained, I'll have to do that later.

BTW, since the OP expressed the problem in the continuous-time domain, I just stuck with that.  But of course, this needs to be performed in the discrete-time domain with $x[n]=x(nT)$ and and $y[n]=y(nT)$ where $T = \frac{1}{f_\mathrm{s}}$ is the sampling period and $f_\mathrm{s}$ is the sample rate.